Why Input box value not force reset to old value if new value not accepted using x-data and x-model in Alpinejs
Having this html element:
<input x-data="myInput" type="number" x-model="dataInput" >

And this corresponding js:
document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
Alpine.data('myInput', () => ({
  '_dataInput': 50,
  get dataInput() { return this._dataInput},
  set dataInput(val) {
    if (val <100) {
      this._dataInput = val;
      console.log("new value is:"+this._dataInput);
    } else {
      console.log('input out of range');
      console.log('current value is:'+this._dataInput);
    }
  }
}))
});

Input box keeps showing any value even if value is not accepted by setter.
I expected the input value to be reset to actual model value if new value is not accepted by setter because when I tried to bind x-model to $store instead of x-data it makes input box value reset to old value if new value is not accepted.
I think it has something to do with calling this function that gets called in case of $store but not for x-data (https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/blob/main/packages/alpinejs/src/directives/x-model.js):
el._x_forceModelUpdate = (value) => {
        // If nested model key is undefined, set the default value to empty string.
        if (value === undefined && typeof expression === 'string' && expression.match(/\./)) value = ''

        // @todo: This is nasty
        window.fromModel = true
        mutateDom(() => bind(el, 'value', value))
        delete window.fromModel
    }


An alternative approach would be to use $watch on the _dataInput  property. In the following snippet I watch for changes on said property. The $watch magic method expects a callback as its second parameter, whose arguments are the newValue and oldValue of the watched property.
So in this case, if the newValue is over 100, I reset the _dataInput value to oldValue.


document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
  Alpine.data('myInput', () => ({
    init() {
      this.$watch('_dataInput', (newVal, oldVal) => {
        if (newVal > 100) this._dataInput = oldVal;
      });

    },
    '_dataInput': 50,

  }))
});
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<input x-data="myInput" type="number" x-model="_dataInput">



